# pass uploader file and form filed value to the one action in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

i have one form and one uploader (i use PLUploader) and want user fill textboxs and select image in PLUploader and when click on submit button , i pass image and textboxs value to one action , i write this code, but alwaye i get null in textboxs value but get image in action ,i think this problem related to call the one action with form and PLuploader,

```
public ActionResult Insert(News news, HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {

// i get null in new but get file in HttpPostedFileBase 

            int result = 0;

            HttpPostedFileBase FileData = Request.Files[0];

            string fileName = null;

            fileName = Path.GetFileName(FileData.FileName);

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

               //do some thing

            }

            else
            {
                return View(news);
            }
        }


@using (Html.BeginForm("Insert", "News", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
        <div class="col-xs-12">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NewsTitle)

                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.NewsTitle, new { @class = "form-control",@name="title" })

                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NewsTitle)

        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12">

                <div id="uploader" class="img-plc">
                    <p>You browser doesn't have Flash, Silverlight, Gears, BrowserPlus or HTML5 support.</p>
                </div>
                <ul id="gallery"></ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12">

                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NewsText, new { @class = "text-right" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NewsText)

                @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.NewsText, new { @rows = "10", @cols = "80", @class = "text-editor", @name = "title" })

        </div>

        <button type="submit">Submit</button>

}


    var uploader = $("#uploader").pluploadQueue({
            // General settings
            runtimes: 'html5,gears,flash,silverlight,browserplus,html4',
            url: '@Url.Action("Insert", "News")',
            max_file_size: '10mb',
            chunk_size: '1mb',
            unique_names: true,
            multi_selection: false,
            multiple_queues: false,

            // Specify what files to browse for
            filters: [
                { title: "Image files", extensions: "jpg,png" }
            ],

            // Flash settings
            flash_swf_url: '/Scripts/Moxie.swf',

            // Silverlight settings
            silverlight_xap_url: '/Scripts/Moxie.xap'

        })

$('form').submit(function (e) {
            var uploader = $('#uploader').pluploadQueue();

            // Files in queue upload them first
            if (uploader.files.length > 0) {
                // When all files are uploaded submit form
                uploader.bind('StateChanged', function () {
                    if (uploader.files.length === (uploader.total.uploaded + uploader.total.failed)) {
                        $('form')[0].submit();
                    }
                });

                uploader.start();
            } else {
                alert('You must queue at least one file.');
            }

            return false;
        });
```

how i can fixed this ? 
i want get news and file in this action

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're not submitting your whole form; instead you're capturing the submit action with the jQuery event handler for `onSubmit`:

```
$('form').submit(function (e) { ... });
```

If you want to do it this way, you'll have to serialize your `News` model inside this jQuery code block as well and post it along with the file upload.

I would just stick the `HttpPostedFileBase` inside the News model and use the normal form submit though.

Comment: thanks for your replay,can you show me sample code ?